# div how to fill parent in css

Tags: html, css

I have a div for setting background, but my output shows that div is not fill parent, it still has little white space at top:
[image]

Below is my code:
HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="bg-image"></div>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="wrap">
            <label>Welcome</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.bg-image { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/background_blurred.jpg); 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
.wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid #8AC007;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
html,body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.bg-image { 
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 background-image: url(../images/background_blurred.jpg);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try stripping the margin and padding. I use:

```
    *{margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
```

this will reset the margins and padding on all elements. Meaning you will need to set your own for paragraphs and headers, etc.

Optionally, you could strip the margins and padding of just the html and body tag.

```
 html, body
 {margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
```